# What's the alternative to .notifyItemInserted() for multiple items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using a RecyclerView and `.notifyItemInserted` only inserts one item into the RecyclerView. How would I do that say, for multiple items? I want to AVOID using `.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Say I have `25 items`, I want to insert `another 20`, what method would I call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `notifyItemRangeInserted` to notify for multiple insertion.

```
void notifyItemRangeInserted (int positionStart, int itemCount)
```

According [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRangeInserted(int,%20int))

> Notify any registered observers that the currently reflected `itemCount`
>   items starting at `positionStart` have been newly inserted. The items
>   previously located at `positionStart` and beyond can now be found
>   starting at position `positionStart + itemCount`.